# Excel clears cell after I switch windows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I almost never use Excel. I have multiple Excel windows open. When I type something in a cell without pressing "enter", then switch to another window, the cell gets cleared.

How do I get Excel to stop deleting what I type/

Answer (score 0):

If using Excel 2010, you can prevent Excel from automatically clearing/confirming unconfirmed text every time you switch between Excel windows by opening each Excel workbook in a separate Excel instance. This does not solve the problem if you switch to another application entirely. There are pros and cons to opening each workbook in a separate instance, so this may not be the solution you are after.

To open a separate instance of Excel:

1. Open the first workbook
2. Open the Excel program again (e.g. from a start menu shortcut) rather than opening the workbook.
3. In the second Excel window, open the second workbook needed (e.g. drag the workbook onto the window).

More info on instances here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/what-are-excel-instances-and-why-is-this-important/20c39a6f-0857-4033-b713-18bf72e91d8b
I believe newer versions of Excel have different behaviour for displaying workbooks side by side in the same instance, so instances may work differently.

Opening each Excel workbook in a different instance of Excel means you can put two windows side by side so they are both visible at once, however pasting data works differently. Formulas are only pasted as text without formatting, and cells that are displayed as "#########" because the column is not wide enough are sometimes pasted as "#########" without the data behind it.